# How to Verify XML Digital Signature in python (xmldsig)

Tags: python, security, cryptography, x509certificate, pyopenssl

I have a XML file and it has data along with SignatureValue, DigestValue, X509Certificate and uses XMLDSig algorithm.
Now how can I verify that XML file is not tampered or it is genuine in Python?

NOTE : I have seen a working online web-app which works fine. But i cant use their python module because of restriction and I don't know how to implement it.([Click here](https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml))

XML file :

```
<UAPermission >
  ... 
  __DATA__
  ... 

    <Signature
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>AdloS35VBgQfq8DuhFejKwSod/RMJM7WutOp2+WiPn0=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>F1ep3IZDj/0ERuOBNOrzx01zq4tFr4zFymerr0lniZ+OCzm/OzBBPue5TQqY032mYK5XZyGVftawa4M21OzxXas+m5ImreV2vV1AGKBxsopkq2pqq77QXMCIS3szDopVfhsGnjAEqgfWQCVwh/yy+5IsYR+9t+d7U1bAgjq+KGkj2v1RohgTV0AIWvePdP2rjFbA2klHgv0W0thhN2JXMRukpzx4xGYiIKkza3dxqXfmmcC2qOGHAOyjVPOrtpT9k/0X2U8UWq4YDN0rF5D/a8lyE+JGVY0NXDjOIfti+POYlh1VLSreWdwjWwiSXxDUrsd4sAbpnd/eMOXCmDUluw==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIICujCCAaICCQDGxXPQwumdKDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAfMQswCQYDVQQGEwJp
bjEQMA4GA1UECgwHZGF0YW9yYzAeFw0yMTA3MDIxMTIzMjVaFw0yMzA2MjIxMTIz
MjVaMB8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAmluMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdkYXRhb3JjMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1pEqdzM106GTx0IHF2J5Tia8rEnXi2tlp4Th
wY0Y8viLnxPX/EGlueEePXWQWw+Dc9usVliWKUDRBHEUZ4FLcxl3QBRkTfgul2S0
6FLLdUfVbeMiSq2gANsjGxNW/+hjkbPsot32fUT0DqboQJLMZzh9s6IEJIe42s/l
tYhziXOln1+oE6M+S7j7r6QHeU25kKMHIBsKD72S3dGBqGimz6ZGJTU3FOmx3m+B
863b9bICAw29nlE4XbkxRZHwGvAfB8yS8Y6+YFRc6lPrVEOOJR/YjnOAtaBhLCnM
t9/Yj3p9fw3QeptZaSNgJ5itnxu7if/9PNuPuUxIZA0n+mgeRwIDAQABMA0GCSqG
SIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQDEuxlb8jUop78g2mwaYbpTAgbpBgJRUVT4VyWCkGRSi4Bc
dHm0zhyZrVuf3GqSwMc+LnRn+/N8AWGHbEvMI7RHSu98biO7T1S6kidsPxKz9CL9
UaE5Wv+RbXxKDhg0MJpHD/WOWbQC3UPs8Ec6sy34QrAhjKTQP1m6zKKDlicmL+29
ku2h/TQv9uEeGa8foL6/bzHAtyYJJC2jovnsBstK9P7nJ1exL0kdqSWQ92xvRqno
sYkLo5k31+gK7KRKwKoi/y+TQDjYqvuZfAm/LmsS1h2TefgMtcbMxF774V3ATqhh
Bt4lFdOhSjgC8E0BhP6TyP+SF5mNAaJ1zhjIYBUS
</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</UAPermission>
```

Comment: There seems to be a module [here](https://signxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which I found using a single search. Request of libraries is off topic, good luck.

Comment: Can you more elaborate this library or tell me how to verify my XML? ( Code implementation)